# How do I set up a godaddy hosting server

Tags: linux, redhat, godaddy

A client has contacted me, requesting to deploy a custom solution (python API and a react application) to his GoDaddy server.

I successfully established SSH connection (which was hell, I had to enable SSH access from 2 different places and use keys + passwords), then I was given a terminal. I tried to look around the cpanel for any info at all regarding the linux version, couldnt find any so I dug around the system and found out that it is running `Red Hat 4.4,7-23` Linux.

The terminal itself does not recognize `sudo` or `dnf` as commands.

I had an idea - installing `dnf` manually, but I quickly realized that `rpm` is not recognized as a command either. I am completely lost here.

Here are all the commands I found in `/bin`:

```
awk
cagefs_enter.proxied
chmod
csh
dd
ed
ex
find
gtar
hostname
ln
ls
mkdir
more
nice
ps
readlink
rmdir
rview
sleep
sync
tcsh
uname
view
basename
cat
chown
cut
df
egrep
false
gawk
gunzip
kill
logger
mail
mknod
mv
passwd
pwd
red
rnano
sed
sort
tar
touch
unlink
zcat
arch
bash
chgrp
```

Here is what I need to install in order to get the API to work:

- MySQL Server
- NGINX
- Phusion Passenger
- NVM (node version manager)
- Letcencrypt & certbot
- Git
- Python

Question 1: Why even provide SSH access to a server when all you can do is edit the current configuration?

Question 2: Is there any way to do ANY configuration to this server other than what is already provided?

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1: You're almost certainly sharing that server with possibly 100 other users. You have SSH access so you can do command line things, but that's not your server, so you can't be granted root access to it. Your access is restricted to what a normal user can do on a terminal command line. That's why you can't use dnf, rpm, su, or sudo. You do have access to a MySQL server, at localhost - see cpanel for details - but the rest of what you are looking for, you can't get on a shared server.

Answer 2: If it's not available through cpanel, then no.

Comment: So basically the hosting provider cucked me (digitally). All I can do is perform basic tasks.

Comment: For most people who want to pay that little, that sort of emasculated Linux hosting is all they need. I believe GoDaddy has plans that will give you full control of a virtual host, but they cost more; and there are places like prgmr.com (not an endorsement) that make allowing full control of a dedicated virtual their business model.

Comment: i am not the one who picked the server, my client picked it against my better judgement. I had reccomanded that he purchase a digital ocean server, but he said that this is cheaper (he got 1 year free plan or something). I am really close to just giving him the code and telling he to find somebody capable of deploying the API on that server.

Comment: Recommendation? That's exactly what you do. Though I'd be at least a little polite - he didn't know, any more than you did at the outset, that it would be impossible to do what he wanted on that plan.